# How to download original-sized image from artsy.net?

Tags: images, download

Here is a nice 60s comic poster-like image:

http://artsy.net/artwork/roy-lichtenstein-reflections-on-minerva

(it might requires login to view).

I'd like to download it, but i couldn't find any way to do it in browser or with other tools i'm familiar with.  Any idea how this might be done?

Comment: Looks like a Zoomify or OpenSeadragon tileset. You can check the sources e.g. in Chrome through the Developer Tools' *Resources* tab.

Comment: Telling you how would violate their terms: "...you must not (and must not assist or permit any third party to) download, reproduce, modify, create derivative works from, publicly perform, publicly display, rent, sell or distribute any Content located on (or provided in connection with) the Site..." [link](http://artsy.net/terms)  :)

Comment: That page no longer exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because providing an answer violates the T and C of the website in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to @Justin De Pustin's answer - the `normalized.jpg` file is no longer in the source code, at least not for pages I looked at. You can instead look for a file that ends in `larger.jpg`, and replace that with `normalized.jpg`, and you're good. For example:

- Page https://www.artsy.net/artwork/misha-kahn-washer-slash-dryer-slash-dishwasher-upright-model
- Source refers to 1024px wide https://d32dm0rphc51dk.cloudfront.net/BbkRBODgCi5qGMiOBVzhIA/larger.jpg
- 4200px wide! https://d32dm0rphc51dk.cloudfront.net/BbkRBODgCi5qGMiOBVzhIA/normalized.jpg

I wrote a very basic script you can run from the JS console that will look for this file and pop it open in a new tab. You can save it as a "snippet" in the left panel in Chrome dev tools under "Sources" for handy access later.

```js
$('img').each(function() {
    if (this.src.indexOf('larger') !== -1) {
        var normalized = this.src.replace('larger', 'normalized');
        console.log('found', normalized);
        window.open(normalized);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it: Go to the page with the visual, take a look at the source code via your browser, then search for the term 'JPG". You'll see many jpg links here in the code. The one you need, ends on "normalized.jpg"

For example:
https://d32dm0rphc51dk.cloudfront.net/ecWm__enxZZAp8LS3rqbfg/normalized.jpg

Copy and past the link in a new window, and voila.

Comment: I was trying to download an image I'd like to use as wallpaper, and found that your method does not work for images that has URL starting with `static*.artsy.net`.